# jQuery How to get the all rows HTML except first?

Tags: jquery

I have a table where I want to get the HTML of all rows except first.

```
<table id="files-table">
     <tbody>
          <tr>
             <th class="text-left">Name</th>
             <th>Type</th>
             <th class="delete-th">Delete</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td class="text-left"><label class="label-none">a.docx</label></td>
             <td><label class="label-none">Manuscript</label></td>
             <td><input type="checkbox" class="del-cb"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td class="text-left"><label class="label-none">test2.doc</label></td>
             <td><label class="label-none">Manuscript</label></td>
             <td><input type="checkbox" class="del-cb"></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

When I use

```
$('#files-table> tbody > tr').not(':first').html()
```

I only get the 2nd row's HTML, where's the 3rd's HTML ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `html` method returns the `html` contents of the first matched element.

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.

You can use the `each()` method, try this:

```
$('#files-table> tbody > tr').not(':first').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).html())
})
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hs4uB/)**

You can define a variable and store the html contents of the matched elements:

```
var html = '';

$('#files-table> tbody > tr:not(":first")').each(function(){
   html += $(this).html()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are not looping through each tr object- so it will only return you the first object which is the second `tr`

```
$('#files-table> tbody > tr').not(':first').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```